# Having trouble making site responsive

Tags: html, css

so I have tried what seems like everything to make my one page portfolio to become responsive correctly and no matter what it doesn't resize correctly. I restarted building it so I could figure it out in small pieces but no luck. My code below is just the header and about section so far. When it resizes, the header doenst resize correctly and text is out of the viewing area past the margins. And the image doesn't resize either. I've tried img-fluid, img responsive. I've also tried wrapping everything within a container or container fluid, and several other things including tutorials. I'm unsure why it won't resize neatly. Please help. And advice on what I should study to become more familiar with resizing would be helpful. 
Thanks!

```css
.stay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #4E0250;
  color: #E1E1E1;
  z-index: 3;
}

.last {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 350px;
  float: left;
}

div,
h4 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

nav,
ul,
li {
  font-size: 1em;
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-top: 17px;
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #E1E1E1 !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#quote {
  padding: 50px 0 30px 0;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #2CEAA3
}

p {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: 0 15px 40px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

#bb::after {
  content: "";
  /* This is necessary for the pseudo element to work. */
  display: block;
  /* This will put the pseudo element on its own line. */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* This will center the border. */
  width: 50%;
  /* Change this to whatever width you want. */
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  /* This creates some space between the element and the border. */
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}

#about,
#portfolio,
#contact {
  width: 1085px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  top: -82px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#about {
  background-color: #696969;
  padding: 150px 25px 25px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="stay container-fluid">
    <h1 class="last">.Scoops</h1>
    <div class="navcon">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a id="connav" href="#contact2">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a id="portnav" href="#portfolio2">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a id="abnav" href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!--end stay-->

  <div id="about" class="scroll">
    <img id="main" class="img-fluid" src="https://photos.smugmug.com/Galleries/Pittsburgh/North/i-LHs7Xwx/1/70f87c14/XL/Winters%20Light%20Pittsburgh%20Skyline%20North%20Shore%20Selective%20Color-XL.jpg" alt="Pittsburgh black and white" />
    <h2 id="bb">Welcome</h2>
    <h3 id="quote">"Discipline is the bridge between goals and accomplishments" ~ Jim Rohn</h3>
    <p>Hey, I'm <span style="font-size: 24px; color:#2CEAA3"><strong>Scoops!</strong></span> Congratulations on joining me in my path to becoming a highly valued, self-taught <span style="font-size: 24px; color:#2CEAA3"><strong>Front-End Web Developer</strong></span>.
      My journey began with <span style="font-size: 24px; color: #2CEAA3"><strong>Free Code Camp</strong></span> and the <span style="font-size: 24px; color: #2CEAA3"><strong>Code Academy,</strong></span> as well as many youtube tutorials. I've learned
      <span style="font-size: 24px; color: #2CEAA3"><strong>HTML, CSS and Javascript</strong></span> basics thus far. I aspire to put my coding skills to use by adding value and making a difference, while challenging myself and continually improving my
      craft. <span style="font-size: 24px; color: #2CEAA3"><strong>I'm passionate</strong></span> about Nature, animals, traveling, giving back to those in need, maintaining a healthy mind, body and spirit, and enjoying great food and craft beer.</p>
  </div>
  <!--end about-->

</body>
```

Comment: use the following meta tag in your html head section <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Hey I do have that in my head tag, I doesn't seem to be working though.

Comment: did you try the same code in different browser

Comment: Yes, I'm unsure what's wrong. I'm trying to make a simple one page responsive portfolio for Free Code Camp and we have to do it in codepen and it will not resize neatly in codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the image is that its width is defined as a percentage of a fixed width container (`#about`). Better would be to give the `#about` container e.g. 80% width for large screens and change the width for smaller screens to a larger percentage with a media query:

```
#about,
#portfolio,
#contact {
  width: 70%; /* CHANGED */
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) { /* ADDED */
  #about {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

This makes both the text as well as the image responsive.

Regarding your header, it is not common practise to use position: fixed for the header. But if this is what you want, I’ll keep it there. But the reason the header is not responsive is the fixed left margin for your class `.last`. Change it to a smaller size with media queries when necessary (just resize your window and find out where it doesn’t look good and add a breakpoint with a media query to fix it.) What you could do:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) { /* ADDED */
  .last {
    margin-left: 150px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { /* ADDED */
  .last {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}
```

With respect to your menu, you define the same right margin for both `nav`, `ul` en `li`. It’s better to define a separate right-margin for your `li`’s (to keep the menu items apart from each other) and a separate right margin for the `nav`. This gives you more control in your media queries:

```
nav { /* ADDED */
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 120px;
  margin-top: 17px;
}
li { /* ADDED */
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 17px;
}
```

Now you only need a solution for the menu for small screens (mobiles).

Merged code is now:

```
.stay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #4E0250;
  color: #E1E1E1;
  z-index: 3;
}

.last {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 350px;
  float: left;
}

div,
h4 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
/* DELETED
nav,
ul,
li {
  font-size: 1em;
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-top: 17px;
} */
nav { /* ADDED */
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 120px;
  margin-top: 17px;
}
li { /* ADDED */
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 17px;
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #E1E1E1 !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#quote {
  padding: 50px 0 30px 0;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #2CEAA3
}

p {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: 0 15px 40px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

#bb::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}

#about,
#portfolio,
#contact {
  width: 70%; /* CHANGED */
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  top: -82px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#about {
  background-color: #696969;
  padding: 150px 25px 25px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) { /* ADDED */
  #about {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .last {
    margin-left: 150px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { /* ADDED */
  .last {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}
```

(HTML unchanged)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use libraries like bootstrap, foundation, simple grid etc?

Bootstrap is a responsive library made it helps with responsive projects for different devices like mobiles and tablets, this is an easy framework to use and can be easily learned from the documentation.

Comment: I didn't find Bootstrap helpful for learning. I just applied classes to my elements and magic occurred. I learned how to use Bootstrap, not how to code responsive CSS. If the OP is trying to learn by doing, then I would argue against using a CSS framework. Perhaps they could write their own though (and learn about CSS/responsive design in the process).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with max-width instead of width:

```
#about,
#portfolio,
#contact {
  max-width: 1085px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response, that seems to help resize the text neatly but not the image or the header. I'm at a loss...aye!

Answer (score 0):

you have a defect in the below block of css. when you are doing responsive don't give fixed widths to any container, use percentage widths.

```
#about,
#portfolio,
#contact {
  width: 1085px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

the below css makes the code responsive

```
#about,
#portfolio,
#contact {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The overall css is not perfect, can be written better.